# Responsive 2-column to Single Column List

Tags: css, html, media-queries

Is it possible to have a single unordered list that, by default, displays as two columns, but responsively changes back to a single column via `media query` shown below?

```css
@media (max-width: 640px)
```

The count of items in the list is unknown, and I would like to avoid using multiple lists (e.g. inserting tags programatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Set by default the `width` of `li` to `50%` and `float:left` inside media query (`min-width` - mobile first approach)

```css
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

#### UPDATE - you can use flexbox to achieve this

```css
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li {
    width: 50%
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try with flex if being drawn row by rows is fine with your needs :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Myrwam 
or play snippet below in full page, then reduce window's width to 639px.

min-width sets here the point where 2 elements cannot stand on 1 line. 320px sets breaking point at 640px, below, only one can be there and it will expand full width with the flex properties (grow:1).

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  display: block;
  min-width: 320px;
  width:50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background:tomato;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  background:#1975B5;
}

li {
  counter-increment: linbr;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(linbr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the lists are dynamic, is it safe to assume you have control over the HTML generation with something like PHP?

If so, and If you are actually looking to break a column instead of spread a list a/b c/d, etc over two columns, you can programatically insert

```
</ul>
<ul>
```

when you get to the list midpoint.  Define ULs to display as inline-block elements normally and block elements in your media query for small screens. You may have to set padding/margin on the ULs to get the space between the blocks to disappear so the list looks contiguous in a single column layout.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that approach, but I don't like like it semantically.  The list of items is really one list, and I'd like to avoid a split into multiple list tags.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @dippas example just with a little less CSS as by default the li elements are block styles so no need to set a width: 100%; and float: none;

Just makes the code tidier (IMO) and if a large site the overall weight of the CSS file lighter.

```css
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
</ul>
```